# How to extract RDD's data to Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd

The obvious idea is to add the elements.

```
ArrayList<String> myvalues = new ArrayList<String>();

myRdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row>() {
    @Override
    public void call(org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row row) throws Exception {
        myvalues.add(row.getString(0); // Say I need only first element
    }
});
```

This, and the other alternatives have been throwing **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable**. I simplified the function further.. apparently I'm doing something illogical:-

```
LOG.info("Let's see..");
queryRdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row>() {
  @Override
  public void call(org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row row) throws Exception {
      LOG.info("Value is : "+row.getString(0));
  }
});
```

There has to be a straightforward way. Here's the stacktrace for reference:

```
2015-10-08 10:16:48 INFO  UpdateStatementTemplateImpl:141 - Lets see.. 
2015-10-08 10:16:48 WARN  GenericExceptionMapper:20 - Error while executing service
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1476)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:781)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSchemaRDD.foreach(JavaSchemaRDD.scala:42)
        at com.simility.cassandra.template.DeviceIDTemplateImpl.test(DeviceIDTemplateImpl.java:144)
        at com.kumbay.service.admin.BusinessEntityService.testSignal(BusinessEntityService.java:1801)
        at com.kumbay.service.admin.BusinessEntityService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$157ddd50.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `LOG` and `myvalues` live in a containing class. Thus the whole class (as being part of the "capture" of `call` is going to be serialized, which is not possible.

### Solution

First, substitute LOG by a simple `System.out.println` and see if that works.

Second, create a copy of the members you are using inside of call;

```
public void call(...) {
    Log log = LOG // or
    ArrayList<String> inside = myvalues
    inside.add(...)
}
```

Third, **never use** an ArrayList inside `foreach` as it is run on different nodes and each node will see its own ArrayList. So, you will never the what you expect.

**Instead, use `rdd.collect(...)` to collect your results!**

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code of what to pass as argument in `collect()` method of `rdd.collect(...)`  to get ArrayList as an output?